# Не могу менять label в новом потоке

Tags: javafx

```
public void initialize(){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (double i = 1; i <= 10; i+=1) {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
}
```

StackTrace:

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on
>   FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>     at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
>     at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)

Как можно это исправить ?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо метод setText обернуть в [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-). Тогда то, что будет внутри этого runLater будет выполняться в JavaFX потоке и ошибки, приведенной в примере, не будет.

Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
public void initialize() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {@
        Override
        public void run() {
            for (double i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```